# Draw line from two points clicked on plot screen then remove artists

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, event-handling

I want this code to allow me to click on the plot screen in two different positions, plot a "X" on each clicked coordinate, then draw a line between them. After that, if I click on the plot screen again, I want the code to delete the "X" scatters and the line. The code bellow is having problem deleting the line (works for removing the scatters). It keeps returning UnboundLocalError: local variable 'l' referenced before assignment. Can someone explain to me why, with this approach, the remove() method is working for the scatter plot but not for the line plot? Thanks!

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1,2,3], [10,20,30])
p_arts = []
px, py = [], []

def onclick(event):
    if len(p_arts) < 2:
        p = ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)
        p_arts.append(p)
        px.append(event.xdata)
        py.append(event.ydata)
        if len(p_arts) == 2:
            l = ax.plot(px, py)
    else:
        p_arts[0].remove()
        p_arts[1].remove()
        p_arts.clear()
        px.clear()
        py.clear()
        l.remove()
    fig.canvas.draw()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's look at what the error means.

It's raised at the line `l.remove()`, and signifies that the variable `l` is defined somewhere in your function, *but* at the time `remove` is called, *it has not yet been defined*.

Note that `l` is a *local* variable, which means that one instance of it is created when your function is called, and destroyed thereafter; it is not passed between invocations.

Then, it is clear that since `l` is only defined in the `if` branch, if the `else` branch is taken, we will encounter an error, since for that particular call to `onclick`, `l` doesn't exist.

The solution is just to append it to `p_arts`, as you are doing for the `scatterplot` artist. I would also clean up the code a little, as follows:

```
def onclick(event):
    if len(p_arts) == 0:
        # plot first scatter
        scatter_artist = ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)
        p_arts.append(scatter_artist)

    elif len(p_arts) == 1:
        # plot second scatter and line
        scatter_artist = ax.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata)
        p_arts.append(scatter_artist)
        line_artist = ax.plot([event.xdata], [event.ydata])[0]
        p_arts.append(line_artist)

    else:
        # remove everything
        for artist in p_arts:
            artist.remove()

    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't manage to get your code to work properly. It only creates one scatter plot (one "circle") when the first click on the plot screen happens. A seconds click removes the created scatter and that's it.

Comment: @VictorJosé My bad, didn't read the question properly. Edited.

Comment: That worked! Only had to edit the ax.plot([event.xdata], [event.ydata])[0]. For each of the two plotted scatter points I appended their x and y values to lists (px and py), then used ax.plot(px, py)[0]. Also had to use p_arts.clear(), px.clear() and py.clear() inside the else statement. Thank you!

Comment: @VictorJosé Okay, *now* I get why you assigned them to variables. Whoops.